# Function takes a long time to return

Tags: python, couchdb, python-3.5

I have a function that takes a long time to return control to the parent after the return call is made.  I've timed it, and it frequently runs between 2-10 minutes.  Here's the function itself:

```
def mass_update_database(database, queue):

    documents_to_update = []

    # Get all docs from queue for updating.
    while not queue.empty():
        documents_to_update.append(queue.get())
        queue.task_done()

    # Update database
    database.update(documents_to_update)

    # Compact the database, which removes previous revisions
    # and slims the size of our database.
    if database.compact():
        print('Compaction completed successfully.')
    else:
        print('Compaction failed.')

    print('Beginning return')
    d = datetime.datetime.now()
    return d
```

Some notes on the above code, queue is pretty large (8,500 dictionaries with at least 20 keys and potentially lengthy values)  This is updating to CouchDB, so the database object is a couchdb.Database object.  The `d` variable is for timing (which is how I know it's taking so long).

I suspect that maybe the `documents_to_update` variable is so large that cleaning it up is taking a long time?  But I ran it with a variation where I added `documents_to_update = []` right before the timer started, and it still took a long time to return.

Here's where it's being called.  The above function is in a different module called NS.

```
d = NS.mass_update_database(ns_database, docs_to_update_queue)
print('Returned', datetime.datetime.now() - d)
```

Anyone know any reason why returning control to the parent could take 2-10 minutes?

I should add that when I take the code from the function and stick it where the function call would go, it doesn't take forever to finish running where the return statement would be.

EDIT: I should clarify, the long time that it takes to return is from where I initialize `d` until control returns to the parent.  All the code ABOVE that has finished and completed.  What's taking a long time is from the return statement until the next statement in the parent that called `mass_update_database`

Comment: The problem is probably related to your client program that is slow due to the huge amount of memory required to send the data.  Maybe try to split the number of documents into multiple chunk of documents. This way, you can see how the update progress.

Comment: I guess this is a **long run** function `if database.compact()`, so your time used looks normal.

Comment: Were you able to figure this out? I'm having the same issue. There's a huge delay in between when `func1()` finishes processing, and when it's parent `func2()` regains control.

Comment: Alexander Soto, no I wasn't, sadly.  I switched to Postgresql because of it.

Comment: jarcobi889 I am also facing same issue while returning the value to the function, but I am using Postgresql. Have you still facing the same issue on postgresql?

Comment: @Rohit I haven't worked on this project in a couple years now, but using Postgresql did fix the issue and I didn't run into it again.